# Order elements in array

Tags: algorithm

My problem is I have a  large array of objects - each object represents some action on device with id `id:ABC1234;type:add;time:1999;12;12`.

What is the best way to order objects in an array so objects with same id will be adjacent?

I know I can sorting by id, but I think maybe there is a simpler way based on some algorithm.  Can you suggest them?

I have found some information about clustering algorithms but it seems to me a little bit too complicated.

Comment: You want duplicate id's only to appear once in the sorted array?

Comment: How many `id`s do you have?

Comment: It sounds like you want to group objects by id. For this just use a multimap data structure from string ids to objects. Some languages (Java and others) offer these in libraries, so there's very little work. In others (e.g. perl), you might have to implement a map from strings to lists. In still others (C) you might have to implement everything or find third party libraries.

Comment: @Chris no, i have  alot ids let say 20k